# Ubuntu and flameshot

Tags: 22.04

I have installed ubuntu on my laptop, and wanted to make screenshots with ease, at my work we use flameshot on linux, so i have downloaded it with sudo apt install flameshot, however it seems to be completely different. When I click on print screen I can select area but there are no tools visible, and no way to upload the file to a server. I have checked all the boxes in preference for tools and what not but nothing seems to work. I am new, so I guess I miss something on the topic.
https://flameshot.org/img/flameshot-hero.jpg

This is what is supposed to be shown, however i only see the square and I can move it and resize it, but the tools are missing, instead there is a small round-cornered box with option to start screen recording or screenshot and add/remove cursor etc, nothing like shown in their website or what I am used to at my work.

Do you guys have any idea how to fix this? I am runing ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>PrtScr</kbd> is bound to the build-in screenshot tool of Gnome, the desktop environment. Installing Flameshot does not change that.

In the guide of Flameshot, you can find how you can bind [Flameshot to the <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> key](https://flameshot.org/docs/guide/key-bindings/#on-ubuntu-and-other-gnome-based-distros).